# Ionic does not load favicon.ico

Tags: ionic-framework

My app was working ok the last days, but today I have started it and it fails in some stuff (incorrect tab position, js bugs...). Then I saw that the chromium console said:

```
http://localhost:8100/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

and after some reloads it says

```
GET http://localhost:8100/manifest.json 404 (Not Found)
```

I have changed my index.html,package.json and gulpfile with the ones of oldest versions of my app that work but it has been useless